# Sort a multidimensional array by

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort the following multidimensional array by several keywords - let me explain in a simple way.

this is how the parts in my multidimensional array look like

```
[template] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [KeyA] => 123
                        [KeyB] => ABC
                        [KeyC] => #FFFFF
                        [custom] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => bla
                                        [var] => 2
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => c1
                                        [var] => 5
                                    )

                            )

                    )
            )
```

there are tons of multidimensional arrays in that template array and I want them now to sort for example by KeyC (#00000 first prio, #FFFFFF second prio, #333333 third prio) and then by KeyA alphabetic.

How to do that ?

Comment: What strange and mysterious logic would dictate `#ffffff` be between `#000000` and `#333333`?

Comment: Posiby duplicate question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511954/php-sorting-object-array-by-certain-criteria

Comment: what is your sorting logic in `KeyC` ? `#000000` > `#FFFFFF` > `#333333` ? doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Whatever logic is behind that, let's just say for example I wanna sort them by 3 ore more colors of my choice. Like first sort priority is all KeyC's with a red farbcode, second priority is a green code, third priority is a blue code. I just took 3 random hexcodes which shows I don't want to sort them alphabetic or numerous. I want to sort them by my own pattern which I can change whenever I want just by replacing my prioritys.
And sadly it's not a duplicate question since I want my OWN searchpattern for KeyC like I could do with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has several functions that deal with sorting arrays and the logic behind array sorting are:

- Some sort based on the array keys, whereas others by the values: $array['key'] = 'value';
- Whether or not the correlation between the keys and values are maintained after the sort, which may mean the keys are reset numerically (0,1,2 ...)
- The order of the sort: alphabetical, low to high (ascending), high to low (descending), numerical, natural, random, or *user defined*
- If any of these sort functions evaluates two members as equal then the order is undefined (the sorting is not stable).

Note: All of these sort functions act directly on the array variable itself, as opposed to returning a new sorted array.

The main functions of sorting are described http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php and for creating custom sorting you have to tricks best suitable to yourself.